# Type mismatch when passing an array to a subroutine defined in a custom class in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a type mismatch when I pass an array of strings to my user defined class subroutine. I initially had the array declared as string type but I have since moved changed that to variant type. Unfortunately this did not solve the issue.

Simplified subroutine declaration in class module:

```
Public Sub extract_key_params(ByRef ECMData() As Variant)
Dim Line as Variant
For Each Line In ECMData
    If ... Then
        ... Do stuff ...
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Calling statement in regular module:

```
Dim ECMData() As Variant
 ... populate array ...
Dim ecmparams As New ECM_Object
Call ecmparams.extract_key_params(ECMData)  ' Call the class subroutine
```

Whenever this subroutine is called I get a type mismatch error. If anyone knows where my error is please let me know. Thank you :-)

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error occurs?  And can you include the code that populates the array, along with the complete code for your `For Eacn/Next` loop?

Comment: In the VBE, go to Tools->Options. On the "General" tab, select "Break in class moduled". Now the debugger should stop at the line that really causes the error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I changed the settings as you suggested. Turns out the error was in the body code of the "extract_key_params" subroutine. Thank you greatly for your help!